# LinearPercentIndicator does not follow the page number when clicking the button back

Tags: flutter, dart

How to solve LinearPercentIndicator not following multiple pages. My problem is that when I click the next button the IndicatorPercent moves according to the page number but when I click the back button only the page number changes while the IndicatorPercent does not. For example, when I go to page number 3 the IndicatorPercent and the numbers move together but when I go to the back page number 2 only the number changes but the IndicatorBar doesn't. After I went back to number 1 there was a change in the IndicatorBar.

Indicator on page 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx1dV.png)

Indicator on page 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCTKP.png)

Code:

```
 Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, top: 20),
                  child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                    lineHeight: 20.0,
                    animationDuration: 3000,
                    percent: _completionPercentage,
                    animateFromLastPercent: true,
                    center: Text(
                      "$_stepno/6",
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    barRadius: const Radius.circular(5),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    progressColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                )





 Expanded(
                      child: _stepno > 1
                          ? Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                              child: Center(
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _previous();
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20, right: 20),
                                    height: 45,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: AppConst.primaryColor,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(5.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: const Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Previous",
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox(height: 1),
                    ),
  

_previous() {
    if (_stepno > 0) {
      _stepno--;
      setState(() {
        _completionPercentage = (_stepno / 100) * 20;
      });
    } else {
      _stepno--;
      setState(() {
        _completionPercentage = (_stepno / 100) * 20;
      });
    }
  }
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue?